# showing received push notification only after executing some function

Tags: android, push-notification, urbanairship.com

Now I have done like this: `Onclick` of notification will lead to an activity from there I am calling an asynctask and then showing the result, but I need a quick loading effect like whatsapp. So, I need to load the whole data(asynctask) before showing the notification that means I have to call the asynctask onrecieve of the notification after it's execution only show the notification message on the notification bar.

This is my BroadcastReceiver

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;

import com.urbanairship.UAirship;
import com.urbanairship.push.PushManager;

public class IntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String logTag = "PushSample";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.i(logTag, "Received intent: " + intent.toString());
    String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_PUSH_RECEIVED)) {

        int id = intent.getIntExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);

        Log.i(logTag, "Received push notification. Alert: " 
                + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT)
                + " [NotificationID="+id+"]");

    } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_OPENED)) {

        Log.i(logTag, "User clicked notification. Message: " + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_ALERT));
        String caseId = intent.getStringExtra("caseId");
        Log.i(logTag, "CaseID is: " + caseId);
        Intent launch = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        launch.setClass(UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext(), CaseDetailActivity.class);
        launch.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        launch.putExtra("caseId", caseId);

        UAirship.shared().getApplicationContext().startActivity(launch);

    } else if (action.equals(PushManager.ACTION_REGISTRATION_FINISHED)) {
        Log.i(logTag, "Registration complete. APID:" + intent.getStringExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_APID)
                + ". Valid: " + intent.getBooleanExtra(PushManager.EXTRA_REGISTRATION_VALID, false));
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with Asynchronous tasks in android? They specifically used for showing results on UI thread after execution

Comment: yes i am.That part i know. I just wanted to know how to prevent the notification from displaying .

Comment: you would write the function body in doInBackground of Asynchronous Task and show the result in notification bar from onPostExecute of Asynch Task.

Comment: code for showing notifcation is what i want.I am using urbanairship

Comment: Please check the code above